# Pivot & UnPivot functionality with dates in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, pivot, unpivot

I'm currently working to retrieve the last 6 available dates data using pivot, unpivot. Can anyone help me with this query?

```
select * 
from #myTable
unpivot (value for Area in (abc,def,fgh,ijk,klp)) up
pivot (max(value) for [date] in (
##-- Here I need to get the last 6 available dates less than current date
)) p
```

Datatype of `[Date]` column is `DATE.`

Sample values of date in my db

```
2017-09-16,
2017-09-09,
2017-09-02,
2017-08-26,
2017-07-22,
2017-07-01,
2017-06-24,
2017-06-11
```

[Sample table, with expected result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8mI2J.png)

Comment: Last 6 or last 6 for each Area? Sample data and expected output would be nice.

Comment: Yes for each area...Added sample table, with same expected result as well.. Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, from your sample data, the top 6 for one area would be the same for each area since Area is the column names. With that information, we can use a dynamic unpivot after the original pivot.

```
declare @table table (TheDate date, abc int, def int, fgh int, ijk int, klp int)
insert into @table
values
('20170916',1,2,34,4,5),
('20170909',2,3,4,5,676),
('20170902',6,7,8,8,9)

DECLARE @DynamicPivotQuery AS NVARCHAR(MAX)
DECLARE @ColumnName AS NVARCHAR(MAX)

if object_id('tempdb..#staging') is not null drop table #staging

select
    Area
    ,TheDate
    ,Val
into #staging
from @table
unpivot 
    (Val for Area in (abc,def,fgh,ijk,klp)
    ) up


--Get distinct values of the PIVOT Column / top 6 by date
SELECT @ColumnName= ISNULL(@ColumnName + ',','') 
       + QUOTENAME(TheDate)
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT TOP 6 TheDate FROM #staging ORDER BY TheDate DESC) AS TheDate

--Prepare the PIVOT query using the dynamic 
SET @DynamicPivotQuery = 
  N'SELECT Area, ' + @ColumnName + '
    FROM #staging
    PIVOT(SUM(Val) 
          FOR TheDate IN (' + @ColumnName + ')) AS PVTTable'

--Execute the Dynamic Pivot Query
EXEC sp_executesql @DynamicPivotQuery
```

**[See It In Action Here](http://rextester.com/CMM9589)**